# How can I list all exported names of a ES 6 module to implement Python's 'globals' function

Tags: javascript, python, ecmascript-6, module, transcrypt

To make the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) Python to JavaScript compiler suitable for the use of ES6 modules, I have to implement a.o. the Python `globals` function.

Currently during tranpilation all globals are remembered in a variable named `__all__`. Function `globals` just lists the contents of that variable.

But with modules, all exported variables and functions are prefixed with the word `export`. So I guess the JS interpreter somewhere internally has a list or dictionary of exported names.

Is it possible to access this somehow, so the `__all__` list isn't needed anymore, resulting in leaner target code?

[EDIT]

Of course it would be possible to use an explicit ES6 export list instead of the `export` prefix. But Transcrypt also allows inlined JavaScript. And variables exported from there with an `export` prefix woulnd'nt be in that list, so it wouldn't be complete.